# Register a method on a class and using it in multiprocessing does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing

say I have a module `lib.py` with base class `A` and a function `register` that lets the user add additional methods to the class

For example
`lib.py`

```
class A:
    def test1(self):
        return 1

def register(fn, cls):
    setattr(cls, fn.__name__, fn)


def parallel1(a):
    return a.test1()

def parallel2(a):
    return a.test2()
```

Now in `main.py` I add a simple method called `test2`

In `main.py`

```
from lib import A, register

def test2(self):
    return 2

register(test2, A)

a = A()
print(a.test2())  # it works, it prints 2
```

The problem is when I use it with multiprocessing the register function does not work. I suspect it is because when the job is sent to the child processes the class A is reimported from lib.py which does not have the test method in it yet.

```
from lib import parallel1, parallel2
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = [*executor.map(parallel1, (A() for i in range(10)))]  # this works 

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result = [*executor.map(parallel2, (A() for i in range(10)))]  # this does NOT work
```

Any idea on how to solve it?
PS: I know I could register the new function to the class in the parallel functions but there are reasons why I can't do that
Many thanks

Comment: I will remove the downvote if you have fixed it. But when you say "this does not work" and it is the same code, how do you expect to get a resolution to your problem. Don't you think that is a poorly asked question because we now have no idea what your question is?

Comment: I think it's quite human to make a simple error like confusing `parallel1` with `parallel2`. It was a copy paste error. Thank you for pointing it out. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be tagging your question with the platform you are running on as the guidelines for questions relating to multiprocessing questions request that you do.

The solution is to ensure that the processes in your pool perform the registration that is required by initializing the pool thus;

```py
from workers import A, register, parallel1, parallel2

def test2(self):
    return 2

def init_pool():
    register(test2, A)

#required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

    # initialize each process in the pool using function init_pool:
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_pool) as executor:
        result1 = [*executor.map(parallel1, (A() for i in range(10)))]
        print(result1)
        result2 = [*executor.map(parallel2, (A() for i in range(10)))]
        print(result2)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

**Note**

You could also get away with just:

```py
from workers import A, register, parallel1, parallel2

def test2(self):
    return 2

register(test2, A)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result1 = [*executor.map(parallel1, (A() for i in range(10)))]
        print(result1)
        result2 = [*executor.map(parallel2, (A() for i in range(10)))]
        print(result2)
```

For example, on Windows each new process spawned will start execution from the top of the program and execute anything that is at global scope including the `register(test2, A)` statement. But explicitly running this as a pool initializer makes the importance of this statement to the initialization of the processes in the pool clearer and it also does not need to be executed by the main process.

Comment: I am sorry there were 2 typos in my code. I fixed it now

Comment: are you aware of any other way to fix this without having to do do things in multiprocessing? the point is that for how the code is structured and maintained I can't go and modify the multiprocessing code. So the solution of using `init_pool` is great but unfortunately not usable for me.

Comment: I don't really understand what your constraints are. You can also run the code that is under the **Note**; it will work on Windows or Linux. Under Linux the `register(test2, A)` does not need to be at global scope; it can be within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. That is, it just needs to be called some time before you create the `A()` instances that you pass to your pool. And you still haven't tagged your question specifying *which* of these platforms you *are* running on.

Comment: the question is not specific to a platform. It is cross platform and it runs in interactive mode like Jupyterlab so the "each new process spawned will start execution from the top of the program " does not apply to my usecase